# getting word under mouse cursor

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm programming in C#  Express 2010, and I want to get a word(such as explaining the word meaning) under the mouse pointer once the mouse points to a word in a label in the form.?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Handle label's MouseHover Event - you can get the Text below the Label using its Text property.